# How to create multiple apache web serve instances in same Ubuntu server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web, instance, ubuntu-14.04

I'm planning to create 2 apache webserver instances on my Ubuntu server, So can anyone help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made some search... ?
[Running Multiple Apache Instances](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances)

Comment: I did searched and found this answer http://someofmylearnings.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/multiple-apache2-instances-on-ubuntu/

but got errors